# load hibernate.cfg.xml in existing java project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I try to load hibernate.cfg.xml in a submodule (ssf/samples/customcontroller) of an [existing project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kablink/files/Kablink%20Vibe/3.4.0%20FCS/). For this project there exists a build.xml which builds and deploys the project properly. In detail it builds a jar file which contains my CustomController.class and other custom *.class files and push that jar into the right directory on the server. If I also put the hibernate.cfg.xml file like my CustomController.class file I'm not able to load this file via

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your classpath is set to the src directory. Then you should use

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Comment: @v.ladynev sorry yes you are right. configure would look in the classpath as well

Comment: I think, It is ok.

Comment: @simas_ch with class path you mean sources under project properties >java build path >source?

Answer (score 0):

HI try to pass  `hibernate.cfg.xml` file path as an argument into the `configure()`

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
                    "/ssf/samples/customcontroller/src/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();

            return sessionFactory;
```

Comment: I think,  It is not correct. You can do it, if you pass a valid URL `file:/c:/some_path`.

Comment: Yes you're right i just copied his link without making attention

Comment: Your edit is incorrect too. Hibernate loads this file using URL or ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

See where `hibernate.cfg.xml` resides in the build folder (in which eclipse compiles classes).

If `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the root of the build folder

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

If `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the `build_folder/some_path/some_other_path/hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .configure("/some_path/some_other_path/hibernate.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

You can use path without the leading `/`, because of Hibernate deletes it anyway (it is even more correct way, but not clear, because of a path to a resource has the leading `/` usually)

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .configure("some_path/some_other_path/hibernate.cfg.xml")
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

This code shows how Hibernate tries to load `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
public InputStream locateResourceStream(String name) {
        // first we try name as a URL
        try {
            log.tracef( "trying via [new URL(\"%s\")]", name );
            return new URL( name ).openStream();
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) {
        }

        try {
            log.tracef( "trying via [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(\"%s\")]", name );
            final InputStream stream = getAggregatedClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( name );
            if ( stream != null ) {
                return stream;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) {
        }

        final String stripped = name.startsWith( "/" ) ? name.substring( 1 ) : null;

        if ( stripped != null ) {
            try {
                log.tracef( "trying via [new URL(\"%s\")]", stripped );
                return new URL( stripped ).openStream();
            }
            catch (Exception ignore) {
            }

            try {
                log.tracef( "trying via [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(\"%s\")]", stripped );
                final InputStream stream = getAggregatedClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( stripped );
                if ( stream != null ) {
                    return stream;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @StellaMaris There is a folder in your project which Eclipse uses to build files — `bin` or `build`.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/c9yEa.png) is my project structure. I downloaded this project [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kablink/files/Kablink%20Vibe/3.4.0%20FCS/). And I added sample/customcontroller/src/resources to my java build path > sources.

Comment: I build a jar file which doesn't contains hibernate.cgf.xml file. I also tried the build after I put the file into several places in the project directory. When I was playing around with Spring-Hibernate. The only possibility to load the BeanLocation.xml was via "classpath*:BeanLocation.xml". But then it stops by loading the files which are written in the BeanLocation.xml

Comment: @StellaMaris There is a snippet in my answer from Hibernate sources. It is the way how Hibernate try to load `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Try to load this file yourself, for an example using a class loader.

Comment: You mean to load the file via `File conf = new File("path/hibernate.cfg.xml");` or `InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path/hibernate.cfg.xml");` but I dont know the exact path like before.

Comment: @StellaMaris `URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource("path/hibernate.cfg.xml");
System.out.println(url);`

Comment: I do not execute the code on my locale machine. Hence I have no idea which path I should use to load the resource. The output of `URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"); response.getWriter().print(url);` is "null"

Comment: @StellaMaris `null` because of it is not found.

Comment: But the file is still there as you can see in the linked [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H6bci.png)

Comment: finally I get the path via `URL url = CustomController.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
  response.getWriter().print(url.getPath());` The output is "file:/opt/novell/teaming/apache-tomcat/lib/ext/teaming-sample-customcontroller.jar!/org/kablink/teaming/samples/customcontroller/hibernate.cfg.xml"

Comment: @StellaMaris Please, read my answer. You should specify a path to the file without a leading `/` for `getResource()` and with or without for `configure()`.

Comment: @StellaMaris For a classloader It will be `org/kablink/teaming/samples/customcontroller/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: if I try to run `URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");response.getWriter().print(url.getPath());` I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: @StellaMaris `URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("org/kablink/teaming/samples/customcontroller/hibernate.cfg.xml");‌​`

Comment: I dont get the point you're on. how should I know the path before I printed out the path via  `URL url = CustomController.class.getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"); `???

Comment: @StellaMaris If you put it in the root of the jar, you can do just `configure()`.