# Problem about locating Conf. file // Already in src folder

Tags: java, hibernate

[Folders] : https://prnt.sc/ovyrvd

My hibernate config file is already inside of java/src but when i run the code it says :  org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cgf.xml]

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

            try{
            SessionFactory factory = new Configuration() 
                            .configure("hibernate.cgf.xml")
                            .addAnnotatedClass(StudentGettersSetters.class)
                            .buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            try {
                StudentGettersSetters student = new StudentGettersSetters("Tuğrul","Bayrak", "mail@mail.com");
                session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(student);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

            } finally {
                factory.close();
        }


    }

            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe `.configure("classpath:./hibernate.cgf.xml")`

Comment: Nothin changed :/

Comment: Did you tried to start your IDE as admin?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-directory/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039062/load-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-existing-java-project/36039188

Comment: Just did and its the same

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  they are not working too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to solve this.

Created new folder named RESOURCES and moved hibernate.cfg.xml there.

-Also started IDE as admin